# Android: Question about size/resolution independent applications?

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, screen

I apologize in advance for asking this question, I know similar questions have already been asked hundreds of times, but despite the fact that I read the [Android Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) guide several times, I still don't understand how to create a basic layout that fits several screen without being able to use proportional dimensions.

So basically, if I sum-up what this guide tells us to do:

- We should create several layout resources for each "size group" and "density group" of devices you want your app to be compatible with.
- We should use `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` instead of `AbsoluteLayout`
- We should use `dp` dimensions instead of `px` dimensions to get rid of the density difference problem.

Ok. This makes sense.

Now, here are my questions (I apologize in advance for their silliness):

- Why do I have to create different layout resources for different `density groups` if I use `Density Independent Pixels (dp)` dimensions?
- I suppose that the point of having different sets of resources for different screen sizes is that you might want your application layout to look different on a small and a large device, not to have the exact same layout with different dimensions, correct? So basically it means that if I just want an application that looks exactly the same on all devices (just shrinking/expanding to fit the screen size), I only have to define one set of resources, correct?
- If I want to create a really simple layout, that just contains two buttons, where each buttons take 50% of the screen's width, how do I do that by just using `dp` dimensions?

Thank you, and sorry again for going over this topic again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to create different layouts. I mostly only use one layout for portrait and one for landscape mode leaving everything else to the system.

If you want to get 2 buttons of the same size just use

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

for both buttons and put them into a linear layout container.

edit (complete code, will give two buttons side by side):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/b1" android:onClick="btn1" />
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/b2" android:onClick="btn2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just for explanation: without android:layout_weight="1" each button would take up all the space and the android:layout_weight="1" lets them shrink by the same value to fit the screen (or layout). You could also use android:layout_weight="2" for one and android:layout_weight="3" for the second giving 3/5 (=60%) of the screen to the first button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, but I don't understand how layout_weight works... In your example, will the buttons be side by side or one above the other. Does it only works inside a linear layout, or any type of layout? Thank you.

Comment: the layout should be a linear layout, but can be inside any other layout container (see edit). I assume a TableLayout with fill_parent in layout and buttons might give the same result, e.g. when you want to have 4x4 buttons.